# How to blacklist an IP on TIdHTTPServer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10, blacklist

In a `TIdHTTPServer` component, I'd like to enable a blacklist of IP addresses to block. I'd like to make sure this is on the lowest level possible to prevent any unnecessary data streaming in from a blacklisted client. How should I intercept this server component to block an IP on the lowest level possible? This applies to both IP v4 and v6

Comment: Even if you did this, what's to stop them from using a proxy, or a different physical location, to circumvent the IP ban?  There's no technical solution that will keep a determined user out.

Comment: You could terminate a connection attempt in the `OnBeforeConnect` event handler. Not sure, but I guess an `Abort` should do this.

Comment: @Mason True, but I still need to implement some sort of blacklist and prevent access of any kind to them.

Comment: @Mason, its usually not about banning someone completely, that is impossible as you stated. Usually you want to limit the damage from scanners, DOS attacks or similar. For instance google will limit how many queries on their SMTP you can do in a period of time. If you exceed that they ban your IP temporarily. This ensures them the preservation of their bandwith and also prevents the most naive mail harvesting attempts.

Comment: @Downvoter I'm not understanding how this is not useful, or how this is a poor question, the answer clearly demonstrates that Indy *removed* this functionality in the latest version; something which most users would not be able to guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Indy 9, there was an event for refusing a connection before it was actually accepted. On Indy 10, it's still not implemented.

If you look at IdCustomTCPServer.pas, in `procedure TIdListenerThread.Run` there is a comment in there about exposing an event to the user to let them decide whether the connection should be accepted.

I would modify the source and implement it there.

If that's not for you, then you can disconnect them in the OnConnect event.