# Allow TIdHTTPServer to be accessed only from one client

Tags: delphi, indy, httpserver

i'm creating HTTP Server using `TIdHTTPServer` as back-end for mobile application.

The mobile app send requests to the server to get some information form MS Active directory i want to prevent other clients such browsers or attacker to obtain information from my server.

My question is how i can secure the HTTP Server to accept requests only form my client not others?

I'm looking for guidance here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to blacklist an IP on TIdHTTPServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516818/how-to-blacklist-an-ip-on-tidhttpserver)

Comment: Although the dupe is about blacklisting, it's the exact same solution.

Comment: You could also whitelist the IP in your firewall. That may be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: @JerryDodge The client is Mobile application used by multiple users, The IP addresses will be changed depending on the mobile connection (WiFi and Mobile Data).

Comment: Well that's a different issue then. Your question didn't mention that detail. In that case, you're up to some sort of authentication, which you should already have anyway. Especially for something as sensitive as AD.

Comment: Definitely use authentication. The catch is that `TIdHTTPServer` only implements `BASIC` authentication by default, which is not secure unless you also use HTTPS as well (which you should use anyway). Otherwise, you have to use the `OnParseAuthentication` event to implement more secure authentication manually.